# Keep only rows with hightest date and hightest sequence per ID

Tags: r

I try to group my dataset (csv, separated by coma)

```
dataset_clean <- name_of_dataset %>% group_by(`ID`) %>% filter(Date == max(`Main Date - Info`))
```

However got an error

```
Problem while computing `..1 = Date == max(`Main Date - Info`)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: ID = "00000200".
Caused by error:
! object 'Date' not found
```

Is there any way to overcome this? Dates looks normal like 2021-04-17 in the column

Part of dataset (that how it looks in excel)

[image]

Comment: please include (part of) your dataset so we can reproduce your issue

Comment: your data hardly describes the issue, but do you have "Date" column !, may be just try:

dataset_clean <- name_of_dataset %>% group_by(`ID`) %>% filter(`Main Date - Info` == max(`Main Date - Info`))

Comment: Thanks Ive already added it how it looks in excel. Is it ok?

Comment: Please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: Actually @AmmarGamal you are right. Now I have output that `Caused by error in `charToDate()`:
! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: your data is interpreted as characters, you need to define them as date: use 'lubridate' 
data$date_column <- lubridate::dmy(data$date_column)

Answer (score 0):

```
> Data
  ID       Date
1  A 2004-01-31
2  A 2004-12-31
3  A 2005-12-31
4  A 2006-12-31
5  B 2005-12-31
6  B 2006-12-31
7  B 2007-12-31
8  B 2007-12-31

> Data %>% group_by(ID ) %>% filter(Date  == max(Date))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
  ID    Date      
  <chr> <date>    
1 A     2006-12-31
2 B     2007-12-31
3 B     2007-12-31
>
```

if you need only 1 value for (ID,Date) then you need distinct()

```
> Data %>% group_by(ID ) %>% filter(Date  == max(Date)) %>% distinct(ID,Date)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
  ID    Date      
  <chr> <date>    
1 A     2006-12-31
2 B     2007-12-31
```

Comment: Thanks
Now I have error of `Caused by error in `charToDate()`:
! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`. I think it concerns my ID column which is 0000numbers?